# A Question on the limits of the Fates card

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

At level ten, with my first D&D character I play in a homebrew world as part of a group I've been in for over a year.  I've drawn a Fates card out of the [Deck of Many Things](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things).

Since he was my first character I was advised to play a champion fighter, and while I love my character I'm terribly bored with his class. Is it worth talking to my DM about him using the card to undo a tragedy in his backstory that would have allowed him to develop differently, or are there limits?

My DM knows I'm enjoying my character's roleplay but not so much his lack of versatility on the field, and if there's good story in it he will probably be up for it, I just don't know if there's any precedent anyone could tell me about.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Take the [tour] for a quick site introduction (and a badge!). If I understand correctly, the main thing you are asking is "Can the Fates card be used to change my character's class?" Is this correct? Thank you for participating!

Comment: Have you had a discussion with your DM yet, or are you asking for talking points or rules based arguments in preparation for a discussion with your DM as you try to convince your DM to let you change class?

Comment: More or less. I'd rather not do the meta thing of "I undo my character creation" more that I'd like my character, in this specific case, to undo the death of his father, allowing him to take a different path in life. I imagine the DM would have the fates weave in such a way as the campaign up until that point had happened as it did, except that I am this different class, and my backstory might be altered.

Comment: I did mention it as a possibility but we didn't discuss it at length. I'd just maybe like some recommendations about how to be fair in handling all the decisions, magic gear, and all the things I've done up until now.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Exchange isn't built for handling discussion, recommendations or idea generation questions. We're a Q&A site that tries to eliminate the "noise" of traditional discussion forums by focussing strictly on questions that are narrow in focus, asking about a specific problem, and could conceivably have a single, "best" answer, as well as answers to such questions. I would suggest checking out [our curated list of recommended forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for such discussion.